# Sum the columnar values accumulated by numerous form submissions

Tags: php, arrays, session, sum, persistent-storage

After submitting a form, I receive an indexed array as a SQL-query result and the goal is to sum the column-specific  values with previously collected results.

Example:

```
// 1st query result
$product_amount = [0.36, 0.14, 0.42]

// 2nd query result
$product_amount = [0.28, 0.12, 0.40]

// n-th query result
$product_amount = [0.16, 0.14, 0.42]

// the desired sum
$total = [0.80, 0.40, 1.24]
```

How to do it?

The code that creates an array:

```
function doseCount($num){
    return ($num/100) * intval($_POST['portion']); //getting multiplier for productAmount() function
}

function productAmount(){
    global $link; //connection to the MySQL server
    if(isset($_POST['product'])){
        $product_amount_query = 'SELECT va.vitamin_a, va.vitamin_b1, va.vitamin_b2, va.vitamin_b3, va.vitamin_b5, 
                va.vitamin_b6, va.vitamin_bc_b9, va.vitamin_b12, va.vitamin_c, va.vitamin_d, va.vitamin_e, va.biotin, va.vitamin_k, 
                va.flavonoids, va.lipoic_acid FROM products_list p, vitamins_amount va WHERE p.id = va.product_id AND p.name = ?';
            
        $product_amount_stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $product_amount_query);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($product_amount_stmt, "s", $_POST['product']);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($product_amount_stmt);
    
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($product_amount_stmt);

        $product = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
    
        return $product_final_result = array_map('doseCount', $product);
        mysqli_stmt_close($product_amount_stmt);
        mysqli_close($link);
   }
}

$product_amount = productAmount();
```

After submit, the `$product_amount` array gets new data and this new data must be added to the previously accumulated data.

Comment: If I'm correct; you should check this out. This might help you out. http://php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved with proper use of sessions:

```
if (empty($_SESSION['product_amount'])){
    $_SESSION['product_amount'] = $product_amount;
}else{
    foreach ($_SESSION['product_amount'] as $key => $value) {
        $_SESSION['product_amount'][$key] += $product_amount[$key];
    }
}
```

Special thanks to Mawia HL for his help.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by combining [array_map](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.array-map.php) and [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.array-sum.php). If you're using PHP 5.6 or greater, which you should, you could write something like this:

```
$total = array_map(function (...$vals) {
    return array_sum($vals);
}, ...$results);
```

Assuming that `$results` contains all of your `$product_amount` arrays.

If you want to build `$total` incrementally instead of passing all query results at once, you can do this:

```
// Initialize $total array
$total = [0, 0, 0];

// Update $total for each query
$total = array_map(function (...$vals) {
    return array_sum($vals);
}, $total, $product_amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a number of concerns and suggestions:

- Don't use `global` to gain access to required values.  Pass required data to your function explicitly.
- Functions/Methods should not access `$_POST` directly -- these values should be passed in explicitly so that your code can be more easily unit tested.
- Since the calculation with `$portion` is small and unconditional, I'd probably just build that step directly into the `productAmount()`.
- When you have the rows collected, you can make mapped calls of `array_sum()` on each column of data and even truncate the float values to a certain number of decimals if you wish.
- To avoid needing to rely on  session variables, are you able to adjust the user experience so that they only submit one time after they have selected all desired products and portions?
- Ideally, it makes sense to fetch ALL rows in a single trip to the database. I'd say that your task could be completely achieved with SQL, but I'm not going to the extent of refactoring your code completely.

Code: ([PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/p4))

```
function productAmount($mysqli, $productName, $portion): array
{
    $sql = '
        SELECT va.vitamin_a,
               va.vitamin_b1,
               va.vitamin_b2,
               va.vitamin_b3,
               va.vitamin_b5,
               va.vitamin_b6,
               va.vitamin_bc_b9,
               va.vitamin_b12,
               va.vitamin_c,
               va.vitamin_d,
               va.vitamin_e,
               va.biotin,
               va.vitamin_k,
               va.flavonoids,
               va.lipoic_acid
        FROM products_list   p
        JOIN vitamins_amount va ON p.id = va.product_id
        WHERE p.name = ?
    ';
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$productName]);
    return array_map(
        fn(int $amount) => ($amount / 100) * $portion,
        $stmt->get_result()->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)
    );
}

$POSTs = [
    ['product' => 'goodinya', 'portion' => 3],
    ['product' => 'healthy1', 'portion' => 2],
    ['product' => 'vitastic', 'portion' => 4],
];

$result = [];
foreach ($POSTs as ['product' => $product, 'portion' => $portion]) {
    $result[] = productAmount($mysqli, $product, $portion);
}

var_export(
    array_map(
        fn(...$rows) => sprintf('%0.2f', array_sum($rows)),
        ...$result
    )
);
```